# Scrape with a loop and output each table to a different sheet in the same workbook in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I try to output the tables I scrape with this code in different sheets in the same workbook, and give them a different name but I can't make it work. I quite new to Python so I would really appreciate some help here. This is the part of the code that seems to work fine

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from time import sleep

masterlist = []
i = 0

url = "https://cryptopunks.app/cryptopunks/details/"

for cryptopunk in range(0,10): # The range of cryptopunks
    row_data = []
    sleep(2) # sleep time of loop so it doesn't break
    page = requests.get(url + str(i)) #change the address for each punk
    soup = bs(page.text, 'lxml') 
    table_body = soup.find('table')    
    for row in table_body.find_all('tr'): #get the rows of the table
        col = row.find_all('td') #get the cells
        col = [ele.text.strip().encode("utf-8") for ele in col]
        row_data.append(col) #append all in the file 
    masterlist.append (row_data)
    i = i+1
    print: i
    df = pd.DataFrame(masterlist).T
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('group1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer,index=False)
    writer.save()
```

But this is the part of code that I tried to use to output the tables but it doesn't work

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(masterlist).T
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('group1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer,index=False)
    writer.save()
```

What I get with this code is the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WA7Qi.png)

I would like the tables to have also the following column header:

`header=['Type', 'From', 'To', 'Amount', 'Txn']`

Thanks

Comment: What does not work? are you getting some error ? or unexpected output?

Comment: The excel file is basically empty. If I run this code
`df = pd.DataFrame(masterlist).T
 writer = pd.ExcelWriter('group1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
 df.to_excel(writer,index=False)
 writer.save()
`
It will output the tables in different columns in the same sheet. But there will be no headers.

Comment: You want to write the dataframe to multiple sheets as I understand, where exactly have you placed this line `df.to_excel` can you share ur full code

Comment: Yes. I want each table scraped to be in a different sheet. And have the columns. I can't share the enitre code in the comment unfortunately but I have placed the `df.to_excel` inside the `for cryptopunk....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way to write dataframes to multiple sheets in Excel.

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from time import sleep

masterlist = []
url = "https://cryptopunks.app/cryptopunks/details/"
num_cryptopunks = 10
for i, cryptopunk in zip(range(num_cryptopunks), range(num_cryptopunks)): # The range of cryptopunks
    row_data = []
    sleep(2) # sleep time of loop so it doesn't break
    page = requests.get(url + str(i)) #change the address for each punk
    soup = bs(page.text, 'lxml') 
    table_body = soup.find('table')    
    for row in table_body.find_all('tr'): #get the rows of the table
        col = row.find_all('td') #get the cells
        col = [ele.text.strip().encode("utf-8") for ele in col]
        row_data.append(col) #append all in the file 

    df = pd.DataFrame(row_data)
    masterlist.append (df)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('group1.xlsx'   )###, engine='xlsxwriter')
for cryptopunk, df in zip(range(num_cryptopunks), masterlist):
    df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=str(cryptopunk),index=False, header = ['Type', 'From', 'To', 'Amount', 'Txn'])
writer.save()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I needed. I have spent like hours trying to figure this out. But as I said I am new to Python so still a lot to learn. I will study your code as part of self-learning Python. Cheers